# Will Firebase replace all my cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

In our organization, we have a repo for all cloud-functions. They are all in Python. We've had to create another cloud-function and we've decided to write it in NodeJS.

This new cloud-function is in a new repo, in a new project. There's no relationship between the old functions and the new one.

I've read that if I use `firebase deploy --only functions`, it will deploy all functions in the `index.js` file, but I'm not sure if it will remove the other ones, since there is nothing in my `index.js` file about the other cloud-functions written in Python.

Is it safe to deploy my new function with `firebase deploy --only functions`? I don't want to replace the other functions, just add my new function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you run `firebase deploy` or firebase deploy --only functions, Firebase will likely replace all the Cloud Functions in the project.

If you want to only deploy a single function, or a group of functions, you can  specify that as an additional argument:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:yourNewFunction
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [deploying specific functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions).

Comment: Thanks! Only problem with this approach is that I have to set all functions to the deploy command

Comment: You can provider multiple functions in a single call like `--only functions:yourNewFunction,functions:yourOtherNewFunction`l. If you're often deploying the same set of functions, you can group the functions together in the `exports` and deploy them with a single `--only functions:yourGroup`. Examples of both are shown in the documentation I linked.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this out, whenever deploying functions by using `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only functions` and the `index.js` does not find the name of a function it will display this message:

```
The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
        <function_name>(<region>)

If you are renaming a function or changing its region, it is recommended that you create the new function first before deleting the old one to prevent event loss. For more info, visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify
```

If a function has the same name as one of the Cloud Functions already deployed it will replace the older function. But if it has a different name it should not be replaced and you should be safe. If you still feel unsure feel free to test this out with quick start functions.